# how to get property value using Jena

Tags: jena, apache-jena

I'm using Apache Jena to query DBpedia to get the Wikipedia URL for a specific topic.

So I load the model using

```
    Model teamModel= RDFDataMgr.loadModel(teamURLStrInDBPedia+".rdf");
```

Then I want to access `isPrimaryTopicOf` property but not sure how to do it without running another SPARQL query on this new model.

An example page is http://dbpedia.org/page/Chicago_Cubs

Comment: You can use Jena's RDF API.  See documentation.

(Is there a reason you do not want to use a SPARQL query on "teamModel"?)

Comment: why do I have to write a query to get a single value? Isn't it more convenient to get it directly?

Comment: You don't have to.  You can use the API if you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by accessing a property. You can use a the SimpleSelector class to get the statements that use that property.

```
teamModel.listStatements(new SimpleSelector(null, FOAF.isPrimaryTopicOf, (RDFNode) null))
```